# Two Checkboxes Being Checked at the Same Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **two checkboxes**.  What I need is when someone checks one of the boxes, it will **automatically check the other one** as well.  And vice versa, if someone **unchecks** one of the boxes, it **unchecks both**.  This is a bundle package on the form and they can not get one without the other.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="100">Voicemail<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2" value="50">VM Support
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The input tag needs to be closed:

`<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="100">Voicemail</input><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2" value="50">VM Support</input>`

Comment: The solution by Lucas Green is your best bet, else you are using javascript, and whilst it may work, it can be disabled, and in that case the check sync wont take place.  So consolidate the form, mutually inclusive = single option.

Comment: so how many checkbox bundles are gonna be in the page

Comment: The tags on the question are for javascript/jquery, so I would assume that there is a requirement for two checkboxes and that a solution that requires javascript and not just html would be acceptable.

Comment: @doublesharp Fair one,  Excellent point.  Only reasonable to assume that user1708740 knows their requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to only test these two checkboxes (and not every one on the page), you can use a [jQuery Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to access the `onClick` event for both. Using `this` you can test the checked status of the checkbox that was just clicked, and then assign that status of both checkboxes to match the one that was just clicked.

```
$('#chk1, #chk2').on('click', function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#chk1, #chk2').attr('checked', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not this?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="100">
<label for="chk1">Voicemail and VM Support</label>
```

Comment: This customer needs it to show on two separate lines when the form is submitted to be imported into their ERP solution, hence the two checkbox method :(

Comment: @user1708740  Cant you use a hidden field?  If you tie the checks together with script it wont work for everyone.

Comment: This is technically a better design, but doesn't meet the requirements of the question - very likely that there is a business requirement that necessitates as less than perfect technical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#chk1 , #chk2').on('click', function(){

    $('#chk1 , #chk2').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/n4C3j/)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nj5td/)

Comment: It changes values of all checkboxes in the document.