# Two Checkboxes Being Checked at the Same Time at the same row

Tags: php, checkbox

I know this question have already been answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655407/two-checkboxes-being-checked-at-the-same-time) but what if i only want to check the checkbox beside the other checkbox.

just is like this

```
+-------------------------------+
|column1    | column2 |column3  |
+-------------------------------+
|check here |   ✓     |  ✓     |
+-------------------------------+
|butnothere |    □    |   □     |
+-------------------------------+
```

I've tried this function

```
$('#chk1, #chk2').on('click', function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#chk1, #chk2').attr('checked', checked);
});
```

but it checks all of my checkboxes like this.

```
+-------------------------------+
|column1    | column2 |column3  |
+-------------------------------+
|check here |   ✓     |   ✓    |
+-------------------------------+
|butnothere |   ✓     |   ✓    |
+-------------------------------+
```

here is my html table(short copy).

```
<tr>
    <td width="20">
        <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
        <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
```

just like the one from above.

Comment: How you are going to use class B.
If you can make it a little bit clear then we may suggest something better.

Answer (score 3):

You have a regular Java class. So, stop using Android methods. Just use regular setters or constructors.

For example,

```
public class B {
   private int productId; 
   public void setProductId(int id) { productId = id; }
}
```

Or

```
public class B {
   private int productId; 
   public B(int productId) { this.productId = productId; }
}
```

---

```
public class A extends Activity {

    ...

    final B b = new B();

    LV_Data.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int idProduct = (int) view.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idProduct + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetDataList.class);

        b.setProductId(idProduct);
        // or B b = new B(idProduct); // but, you can't access this outside of the click listener

        }
    });

}
```

As soon as you lose this class, you lose the data in `b`, though

Comment: This is what im looking for Thank You sir, what i only need is a simple Setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences`

Below are the examples to set and get the value from shared preferences.

1. **Set the Value**

   `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Use your prefered name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("val", 1);
    editor.apply();`
2. **Get the Value**

To use shared preference in non-activity class, follow below steps

1. Create static variable for context in your main activity.

   `public static Context appContext;`
2. In onCreate method initialize the context

   `public void onCreate() {
       appContext= getApplicationContext();
   }`
3. Create getter method in same class.

   `public static Context getAppContext(){
       return appContext;
   }`
4. In your java class, you need to call below context method.

   `Context applicationContext = MyActivity.getAppContext();`
5. Use  `PreferenceManager` Class to get the `SharedPreferences` .

   `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
   int val = prefs.getInt("val", 0); // where 0 is the default value.`

Comment: May I know why it's downvoted? What's wrong in the answer? If you want to downvote then please mention the reason..

Comment: How do you get the SharedPreferences in the other class? `getSharedPreferences` only works in Activities

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. @cricket_007 I have edited my answer.. It is OK now?

Comment: That will work, though you should really consider using an `Application` class or singleton object rather than a static method on an Activity

Comment: you can use sharedpreferences in a non activity class,

Answer (score 0):

use constructor

```
public class B{
    private int num;
    public B(int num){
       this.num = num;
    }
}
```

call it

```
B b = new B(idProduct);
```